# list::remove_if using () operator with std::function

Tags: c++

The structure of the Song and Playlist classes:

```
#ifndef PLAYLIST_H
#define PLAYLIST_H

#include <functional>   // For std::function
#include <string>
#include <list>

 using namespace std;

 extern void SongCallback();

 class Song {
   public:
     explicit Song(const string& title, const string& artist,
     const function<void()> = &SongCallback);
     const string& GetTitle() const;
     const string& GetArtist() const;
     bool operator==(const Song& s) const;
     bool operator()(const Song& s) const;

     static bool CompareTitle(const Song& s1, const Song& s2);
     static bool CompareArtistTitle(const Song& s1, const Song& s2);

private:
 const string title_;
 const string artist_;
 const function<void()> callback_;
};

class Playlist {
public:
    explicit Playlist() {}
    void AddSong(const string& title, const string& artist);
    unsigned int RemoveSongs(const string& title, const string& artist);
    list<Song> PlaylistSortedByTitle() const;
    list<Song> PlaylistSortedByArtistTitle() const;
    unsigned int NumSongs() const;
    unsigned int NumSongs(const string& artist) const;

private:
list<Song> songs_;
};

#endif // PLAYLIST_H
```

cpp file implementation:

```
unsigned int Playlist::RemoveSongs(const string& title, const string& artist) {
 if (title == "" && artist == ""){
    unsigned int sz = songs_.size();
    songs_.clear();
    return sz;
}

 unsigned int old_size = songs_.size();
 songs_.remove_if(Song(title, artist));
 unsigned int new_size = songs_.size();
 return (old_size - new_size);

}


bool Song::operator()(const Song& s) const {
  // My code so far but seems not working, and what about callback_ member
  // what should I do for it?
    if ( (this->title_ == s.title_ && this->artist_ == s.artist_) ||
         (this->title_ =="" && this->artist_ == s.artist_) ||
         (this->title_ == s.title_ && this->artist_ == "")
     )
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

For `Song::operator()` I want to do these steps:

1) Call the callback_ member field.

2) Check if the given Song s matches this instance's title & artist and
   return true if so, false otherwise.

If this instance's title_ or artist_ fields are empty (""), that should be
treated as a wildcard (matching any title and/or artist of s, respectively).
Means if for example, title = "" delete all songs that match artist only, same thing if artist = "", and if both are empty, then I should match all.

Can any one help for operator() function ?

Comment: What have you tried in order to achieve your goal? Did you encounter some unexpected behaviours? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You need to show your effort

Comment: @Fureeish Yes I did, this is my code inside operator():

`if ((this->title_ == s.title_ && this->artist_ == s.artist_) ||
  (this->title_ =="" && this->artist_ == s.artist_) ||
  (this->title_ == s.title_ && this->artist_ == "")
  )
  return true;
 else
  return false;`

Comment: @Fureeish but it is not correct why? also what should I do for callback_ member exactly ?

Comment: Include that in the question. It's close to unreadable as a comment

Comment: @Fureeish sure, thanks, can you fix it, seems not working

Comment: Good, you added the code. Now please do specify what does "not working" mean? Does it do something else than originally desired? Did you try to debug your code with a debugger?

Comment: @Fureeish it does not give correct results, and can you explain, what should I do for callback_ member field in first place? thanks

Comment: If the function does not return the expected results, it's a good time to investigate it using a debugger. Please, do so. Regarding the callback_ function object - what are your troubles with it specifically? You don't know how to call it? Simply use the `operator ()`. It's really hard to help if this amount of information is not provided in a question...

Comment: @Fureeish really I appreciate your time and help, can you just explain the meaning of step 1) Call the callback_ member field. ? thanks

Comment: You seem like you don't understand what exactly a function object is. You can call `callback_` like so: `callback_();`.

Comment: @Fureeish yes sir, really I dont know, can you just give me what should I do for that step, thanks

Comment: I just gave you an example how to call a function object named `callback_` in my previous comment. If this doesn't satisfy you, you need to rephrase your question

Comment: @Fureeish yes and thank you, does remove_if I have writen correct, it uses operator() and also count how many elements deleted from list?

Comment: That's too many questions for one post. I'm sorry, but this is not a mentor chat. Please, if you have more questions, just post them as separate ones