# How to properly Use remove_if?

Tags: c++, list, remove-if

I am attempting to use the remove_if for an array. The array contains objects of songs which contain 2 string properties (artist and title). I have a bool equals operator but have issues with implementation. Below is my Song equals operator:

```
bool Song::operator==(const Song& s) const 
{
    return (title_ == s.GetTitle() && artist_ == s.GetArtist()) ?  true : false;
}
```

I have another function which is supposed to remove the song if either title or artist match the parameters passed into it. Then returns the number of songs removed:

```
unsigned int Playlist::RemoveSongs(const string& title, const string& artist) 
{
    int startSize = songs_.size();
    Song s = Song(title,artist);
    // below are some of the things I've attempted from documentation
    //songs_.remove_if(std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(Song::operator()(s))));
    //std::remove_if(songs_.begin(),songs_.end(),s);
    int endSize = songs_.size();
    return startSize - endSize;
}
```

Comment: What is `songs_` ?

Comment: `return cond ? true : false;` can just be `return cond;`.

Comment: _I have another function which is supposed to remove the songs if either title or artist match_ but your `operator==` only checks if both the title AND artist match. You also haven't really asked a question: presumably there's something wrong with your code, but you haven't explained what is happening.

Comment: if you create value, `remove` seems more appropriate than `remove_if` which expects predicate.

Comment: oh thanks for the catch on that return statement. songs_ is a list<Song>. The Song class contains 2 strings properties for Artist and Title.

Comment: As a side note `std::bind2nd` and `std::ptr_fun` are removed in the latest version of the Standard - they shouldn't be used.

Comment: Related to [listremove-if-using-operator-with-stdfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419292/>listremove-if-using-operator-with-stdfunction)

Comment: @Tas good point. This is just one of many functions I have which covers AND, OR, XOR or Neither. For this question I am just using a small example.

Comment: Are you sure the second condition is what you want? Also, please refrain from completely changing the question after getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using lambda...
Something like below (not tested).
Do not forget to use "[=]" to capture out of scope variables.

```
std::remove_if(songs_.begin(), 
                   songs_.end(),
                   [=](Song &s){return (title == s.GetTitle() && artist == s.GetArtist()) ;})
```

Comment: Okay this would be the correct answer. What can I do in the case of this error since my original structure does not have copy 'object of type 'Song' cannot be assigned
      because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
'

Comment: Then use `(Song const& s)` for the parameter.

Comment: Do not use const. Just say (Song &s)